# Disabling automatic message box on ShareKit on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, sharekit

we trying to disable the automatic message box when we authenticate twitter on an Ios App. We click connect, once it's authenticated, it opens up a message box. We just want to connect, thats it without the box. Anyone came across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, just do not share, only authorize:

```
SHKTwitter *twSharer = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];
[twSharer authorize];
[twSharer release];
```

If you wish to get authorised user info (in the form of dictionary in NSUserDefaults), such as username run

```
[SHKTwitter getUserInfo];
```

for more info see [ShareKit 2.0 FAQ](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/FAQ)

Mentioned behaviour is corresponding with pre iOS 5 implementation. If you use iOS 5 everything is handled by native iOS Twitter framework

Comment: This is exactly what we used but the we did want the second part you put. I have been working on this for 3 days. Thank you so much.